# NextJS does not render not-found page until I refresh page

Tags: next.js13

I am using latest NextJS 13.4 with the app router approach. However, when I test a page/url that does not exist in my app/* code (trying to simulate the not-found scenario), I get nothing in the browser until I actually refresh the page and only then the not-found page will be rendered!

I was expecting not-found to behave similar to 404 page in the pages router approach.